# QuickSort in Java with Lomuto Partition or Hoare Partition

Tags: java, quick-sort

I have developed a quick sort in java, that can work with both Lomuto Partition Strategy, or Hoare Partition Strategy.

Both of them sort the array correctly.

I would like to have it code reviewed to ensure I was able to correctly implement each one of those partitioning strategies.

Is there any reason to use one vs the other?

**Here it is:**

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int array[] = {2, 3, 4, 1, 11, 5, 7, 0, 10, -1, 99, 23};
        quickSort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }


    public static void quickSort(int array[]) {
        quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }

    private static void quickSort(int array[], int l, int r) {
        if (l >= r) {
            return;
        }
        int p = lomutoPartition(array, l, r);//hoarePartition(array, l, r);//lomutoPartition(array, l, r);
        quickSort(array, l, p - 1);
        quickSort(array, p + 1, r);
    }

    private static int lomutoPartition(int array[], int l, int r) {
        //pivot chosen
        int pivot = array[r];
        int i = l - 1;
        for (int j = l; j < r; j++) {
            if (array[j] < pivot) {
                i++;
                swap(array, i, j);
            }
        }
        swap(array, i + 1, r);
        return i + 1;
    }


    private static int hoarePartition(int array[], int l, int r) {
        int pivot = array[r];
        int left = l;
        int right = r;
        while (true) {
            while (array[left] < pivot) {
                left++;
            }
            while (array[right] > pivot) {
                right--;
            }
            if (left >= right) {
                return left;
            }
            swap(array, left, right);
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int array[], int a, int b) {
        int temp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = temp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public static void main(String... args) {
>     int array[] = {2, 3, 4, 1, 11, 5, 7, 0, 10, -1, 99, 23};
>     quickSort(array);
>     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
> }
> ```

I like that you're testing your code, but you have to visually verify your program's correctness. It would be better to use a testing framework and automate that task.

> ```
> private static void quickSort(int array[], int l, int r) {
> ```

One letter variable names are hard to read. 
It would be better to use `left` and `right` here.
Alternatively, `lhs` and `rhs` are common abbreviations for "left hand side" and "right hand side". 
I don't care for them, but they're common enough that I let them slide through code reviews at work.

> ```
>    int p = lomutoPartition(array, l, r);//hoarePartition(array, l, r);//lomutoPartition(array, l, r);
> ```

There's dead code here... 
It happened because you're physically changing the code in order to switch between your two different strategies. 
It would be better to actually implement the [strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy).

You could create a `PartitioningStrategy` like this.

```
interface PartitioningStrategy {
    int partition(int numbers[], int left, int right);
}
```

And then have two implementations.

```
public class HoarePartitioningStrategy implements PartitioningStrategy {
    public int partition(int numbers[], int left, int right) {
        //...
    }
}

public class LomutoPartitioningStrategy implements PartitioningStrategy {
    public int partition(int numbers[], int left, int right) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then you can decide which strategy to use in your `main`.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int array[] = {2, 3, 4, 1, 11, 5, 7, 0, 10, -1, 99, 23};
    quickSort(array, new LomutoPartitioningStrategy());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Nice and clean. Keeps your code [open for extension, but closed for modification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).